# upgrade socket to SSL c#

Tags: c#, sockets, security, ssl, .net-standard

I'm building a .netstandard library, and I need to us SSL on a `Socket(System.Net.Sockets)`

this is my socket:

```
var hostEndPoint = new DnsEndPoint(Hostname, Port);

_socket = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp);

var socket_connectCompleted = new SocketAsyncEventArgs()
{
    UserToken = _socket,
    RemoteEndPoint = hostEndPoint
};

socket_connectCompleted.Completed += SocketConnectorCompleted;
_socket.ConnectAsync(socket_connectCompleted);
```

I use the socket to send and receive data, but i need to use SSL over this socket, how can i do that?

**Edit:**

My question is different because I'm using a Stream, in the other question they use a TCPclient

Comment: NetStandard SslStream - https://www.nuget.org/packages/System.Net.Security/

Comment: @stuartd any code example? SslStream need a stream to be created, but i only have the Socket

Comment: You'd use a [NetworkStream](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.sockets.networkstream(v=vs.110).aspx) to wrap the socket.

Comment: See also [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3725531/c-sharp-sockets-and-sslstreams)

Comment: Ok, so I need to edit my code to send and receive messages using NetworkStream, and after upgrading to SslStrem i can keep using the same methods?